# How Can I Prevent an Exception Raised By a Child Taking Down the Whole Nursery

Tags: python, python-trio

Consider the following code:

```
import trio


async def broken_fn():
    await trio.sleep(4)
    print(1 / 0)


async def worker_fn():
    while True:
        print("working...")
        await trio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(broken_fn)
        nursery.start_soon(worker_fn)


trio.run(main)
```

How do I prevent the exception raised by `broken_fn` to abort its siblings in the nursery without touching the definition of `broken_fn`? Is the following the best way?

```
async def main():
    async def supress(fn):
        try:
            await fn()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"caught {e}!")

    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(supress, broken_fn)
        nursery.start_soon(worker_fn)
```

Do I have any other options?

Comment: Quick answer: yes that is the best way. Also check out `contextlib.suppress`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mechanism in `start_soon()` to ignore exceptions, if that's what you're looking for.

You could also do this in a generic fashion, so as not to build wrappers for each individual function:

```
from contextlib import suppress
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable

def suppressed(func: Callable, *exceptions: BaseException):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with suppress(*exceptions):
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        
    return wrapper
```

Then:

```
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(suppressed(broken_fn, Exception))
    nursery.start_soon(worker_fn)
```